# Convert list of double to list of integer in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, converters

This code :

```
List<int> scrambledWatermark = ScrambledWatermark.ConvertAll<int>();
```

result error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'converter' of
>   List.ConvertAll(Converter)'

I did this:

```
List<int> scrambledWatermark = ScrambledWatermark.ConvertAll<int>(Converter<double,int>);
```

didn't work. How to simply convert list of double to list of integer? Thank you.

Comment: Are the doubles integer values, or is some rounding/truncating needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ConvertAll requires as parameter a function that takes the enumerated double as input and is able to convert it to an integer. It is just a Convert.ToInt32

```
List<int> scrambledWatermark = ScrambledWatermark.ConvertAll(Convert.ToInt32);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> listOfIntegers = listOfDoubles.ConvertAll(x => (int)x);
```

Comment: Also here there is an explicit cast https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 0):

At the top:

```
 using System.Linq;
```

then:

```
List<double> ScrambledWatermark = new List<double>();

List<int> ints = ScrambledWatermark.Select(a => (int)a).ToList();
```

Comment: @DovydasSopa ehm, no this is an explicit cast and is allowed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: This is in my opinion the prettiest way to do this. +1 for that